# Finding duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregation

I have a table called Transfers, and I would like to find all the records that have duplicate values on three columns Doc ID,Amount and Date. 
Basically what I need is to find where Doc id ,amount and dates are the same
What is the best query I can use to find these duplicates?

I tried the following query

```
select transfers.doc_id,transfers.date,transfers.amount,
  from transfers 
 where transfers.date between $P{StartDate} and $P{EndDate}
 group by doc_id
having doc_id >1;
```

Here is what results am looking for:

```
Doc_id  Date        amount
1234    12/07/2019  3,000
1234    12/07/2019  3,000
2345    12/07/2019  15,000
2345    12/07/2019  15,000
4321    12/07/2019  5,600
4321    12/07/2019  5,600
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `group by` for three columns`group by doc_id,Amount,Date`

```
select t.doc_id,t.date,t.amount
  from transfers t
 where t.date between $P{StartDate} and $P{EndDate}
 group by doc_id,Amount,Date
having count(doc_id) >1;
```

Comment: I think that you forgot that on last line you should have a count: " ..having count(doc_id) > 1

Comment: Thank you for you quick answer this is helpful but what about if I have more than one table to select from

Comment: you're welcome @user11029146 the same logic works, all columns should be listed within the `group by` list,depeding on the columns the duplication should be inspected,

Answer (score 1):

**Use This:**

```
select transfers.doc_id,transfers.date,transfers.amount,count(*) counts
from transfers
group by doc_id,date,amount
having counts>1;
```

**Output will be with Count of duplicate Records:**

```
doc_id  date        amount  counts
1234    12/07/2019  3,000   2
2345    12/07/2019  15,000  2
4321    12/07/2019  5,600   2
```